# gorm+go+pg: query for related

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

So we have a Person with a Name. A First and Last name.
Let's insert the Person with the First and Last name and query for the Person by Name.First again. How?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var (
    pgHost     string
    pgUser     string
    pgDatabase string
    pgPass     string
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   *Name
    NameID uint
}

type Name struct {
    gorm.Model
    PersonID uint
    First    string
    Last     string
}

func main() {
    // let's assume they're set
    db, e := gorm.Open("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable", pgHost, pgUser, pgDatabase, pgPass))
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    db.AutoMigrate(&Person{}, &Name{})

    p := &Person{
        Name: &Name{First: "First", Last: "Last"},
    }

    tx := db.Begin()
    if c := tx.Create(p); c.Error != nil {
        log.Fatal("tx.create", c.Error)
    }
    tx.Commit()

    // let's find it

    pq := &Person{Name: &Name{First: "First"}}
    pr := new(Person)

    if c := db.Where(pq).First(pr); c.Error != nil {
        log.Fatal("db.Where", c.Error)
    }
}
```

Error Message

`converting Exec argument $1 type: unsupported type Name, a struct`

Feel free to suggest alternatives, change structs, etc.
No, adding `NameFirst` and `NameLast` fields isn't acceptable. The 2 structs should remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pointer and it will work

Reference: 
http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html

Comment: sorry but it doesn't `db.Where sql: converting Exec argument $1 type: unsupported type main.Name, a struct`